# Unable to update the data in Sql database

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-connector

When i update the data in table using ID , entire column data is changing with new data.

Database name:finaldb
Table name:emptable

I want to update the name in emptable, when i give the name it will update the entire column.

(1, '4', 'YYY', 'Program manager', 'CG')
(2, '4', 'YYY', 'Program manager', 'CG')

Comment: Please show your Python code as a [mcve]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks of a [mre] and other details to meet [so] standards defined in [ask]. OP should take the [tour] and visit the [help] in order to [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use row id:

```
cursor.execute("update emptable set name='YYY' where id=1")
```